# cmake install(FILES ...) doesn't seem to be working

Tags: c++, cmake, installation

I have a project written in C++ and I am using cmake to build it.
The project has many sub-projects, one of them is a lib that is required for the other sub-projects.
I can compile and move the .so to the build directory by using 
add_library, and
INSTALL(TARGETS ...)

However I also need the header files of the lib to be installed under the include directory of the build dir.
I use install(FILES ...) to do it, but it seems it simply doesn't do a thing.

To demonstrate it, I have created a test project via qtcreator,

```
& ls test
CMakeLists.txt empty.hh main.cpp

$ cat test/CMakeLists.txt
project(test)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
install(FILES empty.hh DESTINATION include)
aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})

$ cat test/main.cpp
#include

using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
return 0;
}

$ cat test/empty.hh
#ifndef EMPTY_HH
#define EMPTY_HH

#endif // EMPTY_HH

If the files under "test" qtcreator will compile (by default) the files to test-build.
$ ls test-build/
CMakeCache.txt CMakeFiles Makefile cmake_install.cmake test test.cbp
$ ./test-build/test
Hello World!
```

As you can see, there is no include directory or empty.hh file.
Also tried to use

```
install(FILES empty.hh DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
```

But still see no header files.

```
$ cmake --help
cmake version 2.8.12
```

If you have any idea please let me know.

Answer (score 13):

Using the `install` command to move files around at build-time is generally a bad approach.  The command is meant to be used to set up files and targets which will be installed when the user does `make install` or equivalent.  Since you're not running `make install`, I expect that's why the `install(FILES ...)` command appears to not work.

You have a few slightly different approaches here to make this work.

I'd recommend *not* moving the headers if you don't have to.  Say your library is called `MyLib`, then you can make these headers available as part of the `MyLib` target via [`target_include_directories`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/command/target_include_directories.html):

```
target_include_directories(MyLib PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
```

This means if there's a dependent target, e.g `MyExe`:

```
target_link_libraries(MyExe MyLib)
```

then it automatically has access to `MyLib`'s source dir.

This can be less desirable if the library's directory structure doesn't lend itself to separating the API headers from the rest of the sources and headers.  Say `MyLib` is comprised of the following files: my_lib.cpp, my_lib_api.hh (API header - for inclusion by other projects) and my_lib_detail.hh (not for inclusion by other projects).  An ideal structure would keep the API header separate from the rest, e.g.

```
/my_lib
   - CMakeLists.txt
   - src/
       - my_lib.cpp
       - my_lib_detail.hh
   - include/
       - my_lib/
            - my_lib_api.hh
```

With this structure you can just specify

```
target_include_directories(MyLib PUBLIC  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include"
                                 PRIVATE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src")
```

and `MyLib` sources will be able to contain `#include "my_lib_detail.hh"` and `#include "my_lib/my_lib_api.hh"`, but dependent targets' sources will only be able to contain `#include "my_lib/my_lib_api.hh"`.

So, if `MyLib` has just a flat structure or doesn't separate the internal headers from API ones, you may want to copy out the API headers to a location in your build tree and add *that* path to the `target_include_directories` call.  In that case, if `MyLib` itself doesn't need access to the copied files (just the originals in the source tree), you can use `INTERFACE` instead of `PUBLIC` in the `target_include_directories` call.

However, the crux of this (and getting round to answering your actual question I suppose) is to copy these files as part of the configure process (when CMake runs) or build process (when make runs) - not as part of the install process.

So, let's assume `MyLib` *doesn't* have the useful directory structure shown above, but instead is flat (i.e. CMakeLists.txt and three source files are all in same dir).  We could use a post-build command to copy out the API header to the build tree:

```
project(my_lib)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12.2)  # for 'target_include_directories'
add_library(MyLib SHARED my_lib.cpp my_lib_api.hh my_lib_detail.hh)
target_include_directories(MyLib INTERFACE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/include"
                                 PRIVATE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")

file(MAKE_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/include/my_lib")
add_custom_command(TARGET MyLib POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/my_lib_api.hh"
        "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/include/my_lib"
    COMMENT "Copying MyLib public headers to ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/include/my_lib"
    VERBATIM)
```

Then for `MyExe`'s CMakeLists.txt, you can just do:

```
project(my_exe)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12.2)
add_executable(MyExe main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(MyExe MyLib)

# Copy MyLib.so to this build dir to allow MyExe to find it at runtime
add_custom_command(TARGET MyExe POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
        "$<TARGET_FILE:MyLib>"
        "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:MyExe>"
    VERBATIM)
```

This won't work as-is for MSVC - you'd need to handle Windows export libs (see the [CMake wiki](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/BuildingWinDLL) and the docs for [`GenerateExportHeader`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/module/GenerateExportHeader.html) for further details), but it would just involve something like adding the following to `MyLib`'s CMakeLists.txt:

```
include(GenerateExportHeader)
generate_export_header(MyLib
    BASE_NAME MyLib
    EXPORT_MACRO_NAME MyLib_EXPORT
    EXPORT_FILE_NAME "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/include/my_lib/my_lib_export.hh"
    STATIC_DEFINE MyLib_BUILT_AS_STATIC)
```

If you do need this, you'll have to change `INTERFACE` to `PUBLIC` in `target_include_directories(MyLib ...)`, since `MyLib` will then itself need access to the generated file `"${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/include/my_lib/my_lib_export.hh"`.

Comment: Hi Fraser, thank you for this. Unfortunately I can not try this out because I don't have cmake 2.8.12.2 . But your solution seems to be promising, I will try it out later. Until that I will use file(COPY) to copy the header files to the required location. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for detailed answers. What to do if your MyLib is actually a binary (not a lib) but you still want to use headers? target_link_libraries(MyExe MyLib) does not work in this case "Target MyLib of type EXECUTABLE may not be linked into another"